# AspNetCore 2.1 IdentityDbContext: How to get current username

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, jwt, entity-framework-plus

In the Project I´m currently working at, I need to audit the changes to many database tables. To do so I´m considering working with the nuget **Z.EntityFramework.Plus.Audit.EFCore**.  I´ve been experimenting and it seems to mostly fit my needs. I´ve been following the docs [here](https://entityframework-plus.net/audit).

It is possible to save audit entries in my controller like so:

```
public myFunction(){
   //... 
   var audit = new Audit();
   _context.SaveChanges(audit); 
}
```

But if I do it in such manner, it would be breaking the DRY principle. There is a way to override the SaveChanges() and SaveChagesAsync() functions, and it works wonders. Such thing is done like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.AutoSavePreAction = (context, audit) =>
               // ADD "Where(x => x.AuditEntryID == 0)" to allow multiple SaveChanges with same Audit
               (context as ApplicationDbContext).AuditEntries.AddRange(audit.Entries);
        }


        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            var audit = new Audit { }; //Problem would be here
            audit.PreSaveChanges(this);
            var rowAffecteds = base.SaveChanges();
            audit.PostSaveChanges();

            if (audit.Configuration.AutoSavePreAction != null)
            {
                audit.Configuration.AutoSavePreAction(this, audit);
                base.SaveChanges();
            }

            return rowAffecteds;
        }

        public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var audit = new Audit { }; //Problem would be here
            audit.PreSaveChanges(this);
            var rowAffecteds = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            audit.PostSaveChanges();

            if (audit.Configuration.AutoSavePreAction != null)
            {
                audit.Configuration.AutoSavePreAction(this, audit);
                await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            return rowAffecteds;
        }

//... DbContext Code
        }
```

Now that is a way better option, very DRY and more mantainable. Problem is, how to get the current username so that i can do something like

```
var audit = new Audit { CreatedBy = "my_current_username"};
```

In the controller you can use the instruction

```
var username = this.User.Identity.Name;
```

but this is not available in the IdentityDbContext. I did try injecting UserManager, but it didn´t have a function that might work.

tl;dr;
**How do I get the current UserName in IdentityDbContext when I´m using JWT tokens?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

services.AddDbContext<FooContext>((provider, options) =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Foo"))
           .UseInternalServiceProvider(provider);
```

In `FooContext.SaveChanges`/`FooContext.SaveChangesAsync`:

```
var httpContextAccessor = this.GetService<IHttpContextAccesor>();
var userName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.Identity.Name;
if (userName != null)
{
    // You've got the username. Do something with it.
}
```

Comment: I tried this aproach, but i keep getting the following error System.InvalidOperationException: 'Entity Framework services have not been added to the internal service provider. Either remove the call to UseInternalServiceProvider so that EF will manage its own internal services, or use the method from your database provider to add the required services to the service provider

Comment: maybe my constructor is wrong `public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        { ... }`. EDIT: This was the original constructor

Comment: Yep. Don't inject `IServiceProvider`. Use the internal service provider. That's what the error is telling you.

Comment: @OmarYafer What's the working version of your constructor? I'm having the same error

Comment: @rbasniak I not sure if this was the last version but this what I have  `public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            //Configuracion del audit manager
            AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.AutoSavePreAction = (context, audit) =>
               (context as ApplicationDbContext).AuditEntries.AddRange(audit.Entries);
        }`    and this is how audit entries is declared: ` public DbSet<AuditEntry> AuditEntries { get; set; }`

Answer (score -1):

You could inject the IHTTPContextAccessor service and then use that to get the current username. However, **this service is NOT thread safe** 
Also, it means you cannot then use the DBContext outside of the scope of the web application AFAIK.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: This is actually entirely wrong. You don't inject `IHttpContextAccessor` because `DbContext` has an internal service provider. `IHttpContextAccessor` *is* thread-safe, and it will work outside of a web application: you just have to account for `HttpContext` potentially be null.

Comment: @ChrisPratt but the documentation for `HttpContext` states it is **not** thread-safe.

Comment: @Matthiee: I didn't say `HttpContext`. I said *`IHttpContextAccessor`*.